# Is there a difference between imidazolidinone and imidazolidone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, nomenclature

I've had my nose in the early literature on GFP (Green Fluorescent Protein), which contains a [4-(p-hydroxybenzylidene)imidazolidin-5-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_fluorescent_protein#Structure) fluorophore, and [in one paper](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v14/n10/pdf/nbt1096-1246.pdf) the author refers to the "imidazolidone ring".

I assumed that this change of spelling was equivalent, but I can't find anything that looks reliable on Google (there are also pages referring to imidazolinone, which looks like it refers to an aromatic ring with Nitrogens at positions 2 and 4...)

I don't think I'd know quite where to look on the IUPAC website for the info so trying here...

Can anyone help me understand the variations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [NIST ChemBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C120934&Units=SI), **2-imidazolidinone and 2-imidazolidone are synonymous**. The official IUPAC name is imidazolidin-2-one. 1,3-ethyleneurea is also another name for this same molecule:

[image: imidazolidin-2-one]

---

But, as you note, tiny changes in spelling can sometimes be much more tricky than this. To take an example from this family: **imidazolidinone and imidazolinone** (note that the later ends in *–inone*, not *–idone*) **are ketones formed from imidazolidine and imidazoline**, respectively. [Imidazolidine and imidazoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidazolidine) are partly saturated and fully saturated imidazole derivatives:

[image]

Imidazolidine is a proper IUPAC name, but the official name of imidazoline is [4,5-dihydro-1⁠*H*-imidazole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidazoline).

Comment: Ah that site's brilliant, I'm just used to trawling NCBI resources.

So the -idine refers to saturation, and the -one obviously refers to the ketone, I think I've got it -  thanks!

Comment: After a little more reading it looks like ["oline" is a suffix for 4 & 5-membered nitrogen heterocycles](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/heterocy.htm), [azole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azole) is for similar sized rings with 2 non-C atoms (but I kind of already knew that) and -idine is [just a general "related to term"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-idine) according to Wiktionary... I really need to discover some better info sources though :/